# Hibernate Thread Hangs and never responds

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I faced a weird issue and it is just like a dead-lock. When i call a dao method to save an entity into oracle db, hibernate never respond and thread never comes back. My aim is to save a row when exception is cached. However, Hibernate neither throws exception nor do its job. Just waiting forever(Thread has been waiting for 3 days). Is there any idea about the problem? what did i implement wrong?
Thread Dump is

```
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(FileDispatcherImpl.java:-1)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
  at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
  - locked <0x9cfc> (a java.lang.Object)
  at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:144)
  at oracle.net.ns.NIOHeader.readHeaderBuffer(NIOHeader.java:82)
  at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:139)
  at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:101)
  at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:80)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForReading(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:98)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:534)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:485)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:910)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1119)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3865)
  - locked <0x9cfd> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3845)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1061)
  at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:121)
  at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:121)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:58)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3224)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3126)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3456)
  at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:140)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:364)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:356)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:278)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:328)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
  at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
  at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:584)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:765)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:734)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
  at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.PaymentTransactionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$878a078.mergeWithNewTransaction(<generated>:-1)
  at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.SavePaymentTransaction.process(SavePaymentTransaction.java:49)
```

```
 class SavePaymentTransaction {
    @Transactional
    public void process(Entity e1){
       try{
          service.save(e1);// here throws exception
       } catch(Exception e){
         PaymentEntity pe = //createPaymentEntity
         paymentTransactionService.mergeWithNewTransaction(pe);
         // threads never comes back here and hangs when above line runs
       }
    }
}

class PaymentTransactionService {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void mergeWithNewTransaction(PaymentEntity e1){
       // this line is not shown in the thread dump
       dao.save(e1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you constructing your entity? Are there any mappings with other entities?

Comment: requires new, request a new transaction. Could be that you are running into a lock on your database (a so called deadlock).

Comment: When i call 'PaymentEntity pe = //createPaymentEntity; paymentTransactionService.mergeWithNewTransaction(pe); lines in success scenario(w/o exception), there is no hangs.

Comment: my aim is to save PaymentEntity in failure scenario. what kind of lock you mean @M.Deinum

Comment: As I mentioned a deadlock, based on the database. Something is preventing the new transaction to commit,probably the database due to the inconsistent state it is in.

Comment: in such scenario, should hibernate throw timeoutException? Also, how can i understand that there is something preventing to commit?

Comment: one more important thing is that dao.save method never called. Thread hangs on Transactional(reqires_new) line

Comment: These methods perform just one action, so the `@Transactional` annotation is pointless. You only need it when you're performing multiple interdependent database operations within the method. The second transaction seems to want the first one to complete before it can be closed, and that's where your deadlock comes from.

Comment: i have to open 2 independent transaction. first one operates a few actions then second one take scene when first one is marked as rolled back(in catch block). Second transaction never opened according to the thread dump. thread waits on the transactional annotation(on the proxy object) and never hit the `dao.save(e1);` line. why hibernate did not throw any exception instead